# Stick with package version

Tags: apt, package-management, deb

Is there a way to disable per-package updates? I love [Clementine](http://www.clementine-player.org/), but the 1.1 version removed a crucial feature. I'd like to stick with the 1.0 version installed via a downloaded `.deb` package.

Can I somehow disable updates for it, or do I have to check the update manager every time? The updated version is in the base sources of Ubuntu, so I can't just remove a PPA.

Comment: Found a duplicate (was using other words): http://askubuntu.com/a/18656/44099 Still leave it there though, so that it's easier to find.

Comment: let's wait for some answers and migrate afterwards

Answer (score 0):

You can always run your updates and select what to install or what not. 
So when you see an update for Clementine simply deselect the update in the update-manager, and you'll come out fine.

The downside is that you'll have to deselect it each time you run your updates.

This is the easiest way.

Comment: I exactly stated `or do I have to check the update manager every time?`. But found a better way, see the comments.